# Populating $scope using .getJSON()

Tags: angularjs

I started playing with Angular.js recently, and got a demo project working pretty well.  However, when I attempted to load the data from a backend web service versus just a hard coded array I started getting hung up.  Specifically the page doesnt seem to properly data bind after i set the $scope using $.getJSON().done(...).  Instead of just assigning a value to $scope after .getJSON is done, should I be doing it somewhere else/differently?  I searched high and low and really couldnt find any good examples of angular thats pulling intial data from a backend.

Thanks in advance for any help with this!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you are trying to update the `$scope` outside of Angular you will have to make your model changes using the [$apply](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$apply) method on the scope.

Maybe something like:

```
    $.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.modelData = data;
        });
    });
```

The preferred way to access a backend with AngularJS would be to use the [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http) or [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource) service in place of jQuery. You won't have to use `$scope.$apply` you can just update your `$scope.modelData` directly.

[This post](http://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/kqFrwiysgpA/eB9mNbQzcHwJ) has a good [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johnoscott/dgW73/2/) of updating a model outside of Angular code.

Comment: This is perfect thanks!  While your example appears to work perfectly and I like that you pointed out the use of apply because that helped my understand of how it all works - i should probably just use http or resource since those seem to be the more preferred as you said.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

or instead of wrapping with apply, just call it at the end of the callback function like

```
  $.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;        
    $scope.$apply();
});
```